How do you share a private module between a GUI program and the CLI version on a Dart/Flutter project?
I have a CLI tool writer in Dart. How can I make a GUI tool that shares the same codebase or module so they can both deliver the same functionality? So they can also update each other and evolve in the same way (without publishing a module publically)

It is not quite clear what you mean by "update each other and evolve in the same way". Are you asking about how to depend on a private package? One package may depend on other packages that are not publicly available e.g. https://dart.dev/tools/pub/dependencies#git-packages.

@DanR Basically my GUI or my CLI app calls the function Foo in the package MySharedPackage with the arguments provided by the users, if Foo is updated, I just need to do two "flutter build" to get my two programs updated. I think having a private git package could be the solution for that. What do you think?

You might have a look at github actions. A sample workflow is available here: https://github.com/subosito/flutter-action
